# What alternatives are there for creating a REST-full web service API based on JSON?

Tags: json, web-services, rest

We're creating a web service and we'd like 2 things:
 - to be JSON based
 - to be REST-full - how much so, we haven't decided

We've already implemented custom APIs but now we'd like to follow some standards, since at some point it gets a little crazy to remember all the rules, all the exceptions, and all the undocumented parts that the creator also forgot.

Are any of you using some standards that you've found useful? Or At least, what are some alternatives?

So far I know of jsonapi and HAL.

These don't seem to be good enough though, since what we'd optimaly like is to be able to:
+ define, expose and update entities and relations between them
+ define, expose and invoke operations
+ small numbers of requests are preferable, at least where it "makes sense" (i'll leave that as a blank check)

**[EDIT]**
Apparently, there's OData too: http://www.odata.org/

Comment: I'm unsure what you are exactly asking for -  a better JSON based document format? If neither jsonapi, HAL, collection+json, JSON-LD, JSON-ML, ... meet your requirements, define your own one - maybe based on one of the mention ones and add the missing fields, maybe also get it standardized - RESTful clients are usually fine with that - as long as they can handle it. For custom formats, documentation might be necessary in order for client developers to act accordingly

Comment: Didn't know about JSON-LD, JSON-ML; that was in part what i was asking for, names, so thanks!

Comment: As you seem to ask for JSON based document formats: [jCard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7095) is a JSON based vCard format. [Collection.next+Json](http://code.ge/media-types/collection-next-json/) is an extension of collection+json

Answer (score 3):

> Are any of you using some standards that you've found useful? Or At least, what are some alternatives?

Between your own question and the comments most of the big names have been mentioned. I just like to also add JSON Hyper Schema:

"JSON Schema is a JSON based format for defining the structure of JSON data. This document specifies hyperlink- and hypermedia-related keywords of JSON Schema."

http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-hypermedia.html

It's an extension to JSON schema and fulfils a very similar role to the others mentioned above.

I've been using json-hal for a while and like it a lot, but I'm increasingly drawn to the JSON Schema family of schemas which also handle data model definition and validation. These schemas are also the basis of the excellent Swagger REST API standard:

http://swagger.io/specification/

Hope this helps.